# Let $(x-1)^3$ divides $p(x)+1$ and $(x+1)^3$ divides $p(x)-1$. Find a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree 5.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

**Let $(x-1)^3$ divides $p(x)+1$ and $(x+1)^3$ divides $p(x)-1$. Find a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree 5.**

Here's what I have tried:—

> As $(x-1)^3$ divides $p(x)+1$,
>
> $p(1)+1=0$, $p(1)=-1$
>
> $p(-1)=1$
>
> Letting $p(x)=a_5x^{5} + a_4x^{4} + a_3x^{3} + a_2x^{2} + a_1x + a_0$

I don't know how to proceed any further.

I think the divisibility rule is gonna be used somewhere.

Comment: One way is to use the latter divisibility fact to deduce that 
$$p(x)=(A x^2+Bx+C)(x+1)^3+1$$ for some coefficients $A,B,C$. Then use the first divisibility result to deduce that $p(1)=-1$ as well as  $p'(1)=p''(1)=0$. This assuming you know how multiplicity of zeros can be detected by looking at derivatives. Given that you tagged this [tag:algebra-precalculus] it is not clear whether you have covered that. Anyway, the resulting linear system has a single solution for $A,B,C$.

Comment: Without derivatives an obvious way forward would be to do a long division, and find the remainder of $p(x)+1$ (from my previous comment) when divided by $(x-1)^3$. Then equate the coefficients of the remainder with zero and solve that linear system instead. That looks like a bit of grunt work, but that should never stop us. Unless we see a trick - for that I would need a bit more coffee, and there are no guarantees :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first condition we have 
$$p(x)=A(x)(x-1)^3-1 .$$
Since $p(x)$ is of degree $5$, therefore $A(x)$ must of degree $2$.
From the second condition given, we also have
$$A(-1)=-\frac{1}{4}.$$ 
This means 
$$A(x)=(x+1)(sx+t)-\frac{1}{4}.$$
Thus
$$p(x)=\left[(x+1)(sx+t)-\frac{1}{4}\right](x-1)^3-1$$
Hopefully you can take it from here using derivatives etc..

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide me a little more guidance on how to find the s and t?

Comment: Any $s\ne 0$ and $t$ would work.

Comment: Sorry but @Anurag A $A(-1) = \frac{-1}{8}$

Comment: @Ash_Blanc $p(-1)=A(-1)(-8)-1$, but $p(-1)=1$. So $A(-1)=-1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x)$ be of degree 5. Since $(x-1)^3|(p(x)+1)$ and $(x+1)^3|(p(x)-1)$ there exists two polynomials $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=a_1 x^2+b_1 x +c_1$ such that 
$$ (x-1)^3f(x)-1 = p(x) = (x+1)^3g(x)+1$$
$$ (x-1)^3f(x)- (x+1)^3g(x)-2 = 0$$ 
$$(x-1)^3(ax^2+bx+c)- (x+1)^3(a_1 x^2+b_1 x +c_1)-2 =0 \enspace  \cdots(\ast) $$
In equation $(\ast)$, put $x=0$, we get
$-c-c_2 -2 =0$

Take $x=1$, $-8(a_1+b_1+c_1)-2=0$.

Take $x=-1$, $-8(-a-b+c)-2=0$

Similarily, take $x=\pm2$, and $x=\pm 3$. Finally, we will obtain $6$ linear equations in $6$ variables $a,b,c,a_1,b_1,c_1$ which can be solved by Gaussian elimination method.